# How can I debug a Doclet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, doclet

I am creating a custom doclet that I want to run in my Maven build with the Javadoc plugin, but right now I'd like to test / debug the Doclet in Eclipse. How can I do that?

Do I have to invoke javadoc programmatically? And how?

Comment: Sean, good question: I am facing the same challenge of debugging doclets; although the message from the Eclipse dev group points to a pretty ugly method, it took me I think 30 minutes but it works. If anyone finds an easier way, please post :-). Anyway, +1 Sean for the question and for the link.

Comment: the link in the question is broken

Comment: true, deleted it. It was terrible anyway

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can simply create a main method in your doclet and call (example, see full cmdling reference):

```
public class MyDoclet extends Doclet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute("-doclet " + MyDoclet.class.getName());
    }
}
```

That also works with the debugger.

You might also have to add the -classpath parameter containing all jar dependencies needed to parse the actual code.

Comment: You need to call `com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(new String[] { "-doclet " + MyDoclet.class.getName() });` at least since Java 8, otherwise compiler fails with `The method execute(String[]) is ambiguous for the type Main`

Answer (score 2):

If you are running JDK v1.8, you may need to use the following code snippet:

```
Main.execute(docletFqcn.getClass().getClassLoader(), "-doclet", docletFqcn, javaSourceFilePath);
```

where `docletFqcn` is the fully qualified class name of your Doclet class and `javaSourceFilePath` the location of the Java file to process.

Answer (score 0):

I got error message with @Jan answer

```
Error:(13, 35) java: reference to execute is ambiguous
  both method execute(java.lang.String...) in com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main and method execute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...) in com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main match
```

After change to these code and it work well

```
com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(new String[]{
                "-doclet", CustomDoclet.class.getName(),
                "path/to/src/XXX.java"
        });
```

Comment: This works only when using `start` method, wich is depricated now for `run` since 9.